# QSqlTableModel::removeRow() does not delete row in SQLite database

Tags: c++, sqlite, qt5, delete-row, qsqltablemodel

I use Windows, C++ and Qt 5.11.1. I have a simple single-table SQLite database. This table "templates" contains primary key: `id INTEGER PRIMARY KEY`.When I try to remove a single row in "templates" (using `QSqlTableModel`), `m_model.removeRow(0)` returns true and `submitAll()` returns true. But the table still owns that row. I've found that Qt generated the following SQL:

`DELETE FROM templates WHERE "templates"."id" IS NULL`.
I suppose that the problem is linked with `QSqlRecord::isGenerated`. How can I fix this error?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

As  [QSqlTableModel::removeRows documentation](http://doc.qt.io/qt-5/qsqltablemodel.html) :

> Deletions are submitted immediately to the database. The model ***retains a blank row*** for successfully deleted row until refreshed with select().

Comment: I didn't use `select()`. I will add it. But I re-opened the database file (sometimes with 3rd party GUI tool) - no modifications were found. So the SQL query is invalid.

Answer (score 0):

Sorry, the reason was in overriden `data()` method in `QSqlTableModel` descendant. `record()` method required `data(index, Qt::EditRole)`.